# How can I make an iFrame next to another iFrame?

Tags: html, css

Currently the way the code works is that it places the iFrame on the bottom on the bottom. I want the last two iFrames to be next to each other so that one can hold, lets say a menu and the other can hold another web page. They would need to be adjacent to each other. That is side by side (no pun intended)

Someone suggested float : left. I tried this and it did float left but it floated the iFrame above it one to the left and not the current iFrame.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="600" height="200">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="200" height="500">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

//I want this right next to the second iframe that is 400 width
//which would fill the rest of the screen

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="400" height="500">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

New Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="600" height="200">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="200" height="500">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

//I want this right next to the second iframe that is 400 width
//which would fill the rest of the screen

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="400" height="500" float : right>
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: two columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365371/css-two-columns)

Answer (score 1):

easily done, you just need to set the display to inline-block for those two `iframe`s.

```
iframe:nth-child(2),iframe:nth-child(3){
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[here's an example](http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/JkFhl).

`iframe`s are somewhat frowned upon. You might like to consider using `div`s with ajax instead, utilizing the jquery `$.load` function to load whatever you like into them. You can read up on that [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt... The width of the window has to be more than `600px` for the last 2 `iframe` to be beside each other. I used a `div` with `clear:both;` to make sure the last 2 `iframe` are under the first `iframe`

CSS:

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="600" height="200" style="float:left;"></iframe>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<iframe id="test" src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="200" height="500" style="float:left"></iframe>
<iframe id="test1" src="http://www.w3schools.com" width="400" height="500" style="float:left"></iframe>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LKmyx/embedded/result/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can set the two lower iframes to be side-by-side by giving them the `display: inline-block` style, as lukeocom mentioned above.

However, you should also then give them `box-sizing: border-box` and wrap them in a div with style `display: table` so that their width includes the size of the border, or else they won't line up well with the top iframe, as in lukeocom's example.

Here's what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/L87PE/1/

Having done that, you could even give them widths as a percentage, eg. `width: 34%` and `width: 66%`, and have them fill the whole browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/L87PE/